# Mirrored screens, how to disable it?

Tags: workspaces

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04.02 LTS on my computer, I got another issue regarding the work-spaces. Please take a look at this image below , it shows me double work-spaces, and I can not even use terminal.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Why can't you use terminal? Did you check Settings > Displays ? Whats the output of `xrandr --current` ?

Comment: is it a multi monitor setup?

Comment: @M. Becerra  thanks you give me an idea to take a look at display setting, that was Mirror Displays option turned on, really thanks :)

Comment: Mind posting an answer for it? :)

Comment: yes, tnx  for your mind :D

Comment: @NareZakaryan You can post answer to your own question with what worked for you, and accept that answer for the benefit of other users on ask ubuntu

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh ok, let me do that

Comment: @NareZakaryan  [It's appreciated](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/5666/665251)

Answer (score 3):

**solution:**

open *System Settings* -> *Displays*
and just turn off "Mirror Displays" option and press "apply".

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

you may not open and app while the worksace viewer is open or it closes it but you don't have double workspaces you have two screens. if you have two screens it is working as intended.

as for terminal try : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Al</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

Comment: that was Mirror Displays option  turned on :) thanks for your answer